Tab keymap collision between nvim-cmp and copilot.vim in AstroNvim
I'm using AstroNvim, and just installed copilot.vim. It's working fine, except that I want to use the Tab key to accept a copilot suggestion. However, the Tab key is mapped to 'Next Completion' according to the AstroNvim docs. How do I disable this behavior so that the Tab key is only used for accepting Copilot suggestions?
I have tried adding the following code in my lua/plugins/cmp.lua file:
return {
  "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",
  opts = function(_, opts)
    local cmp = require("cmp")
    opts.mapping["<Tab>"] = nil
  end
}

It hasn't had any effect however.

Here is the code snippet that works for me.
cmp.setup {
  mapping = {
    ["<Tab>"] = function(fallback)
      local copilot_keys = vim.fn['copilot#Accept']()
      if cmp.visible() then
        cmp.select_next_item()
      elseif copilot_keys ~= '' and type(copilot_keys) == 'string' then
        vim.api.nvim_feedkeys(copilot_keys, 'i', true)
      else
        fallback()
      end
    end,
  },
  experimental = {
    ghost_text = true,
  },
}

